# Image viewer flip/rotate

Tags: image-viewers

The old "image viewer" had an obvious flip/rotate setting. It does not look like the new viewer 3.26.1 does. Its help menu says to use the edit setting, but I cannot find it.

Comment: Specifically, this affects users of 17.10 and 18.04 LTS, as the UI change for eog vs. 16.04 LTS was significant.

Answer (score 16):

In the help file there are three methods mentioned. Methods 2 and 3 worked for me.

1. Flip a picture
   Edit menu - I could not find it either.
2. Rotate a picture
   when the window is focused and the mouse is over the image, two bent arrow buttons should be visible at the bottom. Click either to rotate in the direction indicated. You can then save the rotated image.
3. Keyboard shortcuts
   Rotate Clockwise <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
   Rotate Counter Clockwise <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: The arrows are so faint on dark images they are easy to miss, but they are there. The edit items are missing from the hamburger menu, it seems.